# What's wrong with syntax in stored function? (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a function in PostgreSQL that will delete all values from table where first letter is bigger than given letter. Can anyone explain to me why this example wouldn't work (it says there is syntax error at or near "Z"), because if i do this out of function with some random letter instead of $1, it works without problem.

```
create function g3_brisi(varchar) returns void as 'delete from prezimena
where prezime between $1 and 'Z';' language sql;
```

I'm new in PostgreSQL so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the nested single quote inside the function source.

You should use "dollar quoting" for the function's body, that makes things a lot easier:

```
create function g3_brisi(varchar) 
   returns void as 
$body$
  delete from prezimena
  where prezime between $1 and 'Z';
$body$
language sql;
```

For more details see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING